# java - the use of 'this' within the brackets of a method

Tags: java, this

```
System.out.println(this);
```

Why would you use 'this' in the brackets? Is it for printing the references? Or as in the code below for comparing if the object points to the same reference?

```
public void compareDrzewo(Drzewo tree) 
{ if (tree == this) 
{ System.out.println("true"); } 
else { System.out.println("false"); }
```

main method code

```
Drzewo name1 = name2;
name1.compareDrzewo(name2);
```

The other examples of the use of 'this.' are quite straight forward (inner class etc.) Please comment only on this or similar use.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html - first paragraph should explain it.

Answer (score 2):

That instance has a `toString()` method associated with it, which means it will invoke it to print out meaningful information, or it uses `Object`'s `toString()` (meaning it'll print out a memory location, which is much less useful).

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(this)`

is the same as

`System.out.println(this.toString())`;

So if the class of which `this` is an instance overrides the `toString` method, that line of code would be meaningful.

Comment: Or even `System.out.println(toString())`

Answer (score 0):

You use `this` to refer to the current object.

One example is when your want to refer to the current instance of your class, so if you need to call a method with your class, for example `something.equals(this)` or `something == this`.

Another example is explicitly specifiying a class instance of a variable rather than a local instance, for example a setter:

```
public void setMyVar(String myVar) {
    this.myVar = myVar;
}
```

So `myVar` is the variable declared in the method, `this.myVar` is the variable declared in your class.